# Google Tag Manager получить ID пользователя и время клика

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Здравствуйте! 
На сайте есть кнопка, нажатие на которую обрабатывается и при помощи Tag Manager записывается в события Google Analytics.
Я хотел бы узнать, есть ли возможность при нажатии этой кнопки записывать ID пользователя и время нажатия?
Буду благодарен за любую информацию
 Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос актуален, то коробочное решение:

1. Создать сегмент аудитории по событию.
2. Смотреть отчёт "Статистика по
   пользователям"

Не совсем коробочное решение:

1. Создать событие через GTM в котором указать в действии макрос cID, в ярлык время.
2. Создать табличный отчёт где выводить действие и ярлык.